# Scraping images with cheerio

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape images using cheerio with node but I can't seem to be able to select the image, I need to do a for each of all the children of flickity slider and push them to an array but I wanted to start at selecting one:

```
$('.flickity-slider > figure').attr('src')
```

But for some reason I keep getting null or undefined.

[image: Need to get all those images in an array]

EDIT: I was able to access the images with `$('#tab-foto-flickity').find('img').length`
how do I run over all of those to push them into an array?

Comment: Those are probably added to the DOM dynamically.

Comment: no, im able to see the content i want by doing console.log($('#multimedia-tabs-container').html());

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `undefined` because `.attr('src')` returns the `src` attribute of first element found with your `$('.flickity-slider > figure')` selector which doesn't even select `img`s but `figure` elements (`figure` doesn't have a `src`).

```js
$('img').map(function(){ return $(this).attr('src'); })
```

Try with a simpler selector first - select all `img`s on the website and then call either `.map(...)` or `.each(...)` so that you can use `.attr('src')` on all results that were found. Once you get that working, fix your "image in figure" selector so that it selects `img` and not `figure`s.